# How to use Parameter field in a record selection "like" statement?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have designed a report to pull data fields based on a record selection formula that uses a "like" operator that looks for a substring match in a particular field's data, as so:

```
{rct.serno} like "*9842*"
```

(due to the free-format way data is stored in the given field, I have to do a substring match to find the relevant rows in the DB.)

This works fine. Instead of manually editing the record selection formula every time, though, I thought to use a Parameter field ("{?TagNum}") to prompt the user for the desired string, and then use that in the record selection formula like:

```
{rct.serno} like "*{?TagNum}*"
```

Crystal does not throw an error when I save this record selection formula, but it does not return any records after the report is refreshed, and a parameter value is entered. How can I properly use the parameter value in a record selection substring match?

Comment: Try `{rct.serno} like "%{?TagNum}%"`.

Comment: '%' is the SQL wildcard char, but Crystal uses '*'. So no, does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close to the solution.  You can modify the formula in the Select Expert.  Just click the Select Expert icon (or from the Report menu).  Then click the Formula Editor button.  Concatenate or add an asterisk onto the beginning and end of the parameter using the + operator, like this:

```
{Customers.LastName} like "*" + {?pLastName} + "*"
```

Let me know if that helps.

~ Nathan

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, that did the trick! You would think this would be a common technique, and documented in Crystal's help (or at least via a Google search), but I couldn't find anything about how to do this. SO FTW :)

Comment: Yep, it's crazy how the simplest things aren't well documented.